# Driver issues with Broadcom 802.11n adapter on HP Pavilion 15

Tags: windows-10, drivers, hp-pavilion, wifi-driver, broadcom

Ok guys, I specifically signed up to this website due to a major (I hope not though) problem, seeing answers come close but not yet manage to solve my problem.

I have a relatively new Hewlett Packard Pavilion 15 with Windows 10, which has been running smoothly, except for one network card problem solved by restoring the computer. Today I tried to update my Broadcom network card through the HP support assistant, but the thing stopped mid-installation and left me without any internet.

If I now go to my network card settings the Wi-Fi is disabled and I can't enable it again. And while troubleshooting, Windows tells me there is a problem with the driver. When I go to the device manager property tab for the card driver and try to restore it to a previous version, or try to update one from the list on my computer, even those directly from Broadcom, the installation always times out and ultimately does not work.

I don't know what to do, and I'd like not to have to restore the damn thing again.
Help very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I have an answer. However, I suggest you download [ALL] drivers for the laptop from a working PC and put them on a flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working Ethernet cable plug it into the machine and modem/router. From here, you have internet access, but this is a laptop. You want to be able to travel with it. Now that you have a cable connection, open up HP support assistant and reinstall the wireless card driver. If this doesn't work, you could manually download it from their website. Once this finishes restart the computer, unplug the cable and you are all ready to go.

[image]

It doesn't matter what color Ethernet cable you have.

IF YOU DON'T HAVE AN ETHERNET CABLE

If you don't have an Ethernet cable, go to another computer that has and download the driver update manually. Then, put it on a USB or some other form of media. Remember to check your library; most of them nowadays have computers with internet access.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't actually have an ethernet cable at home, but I think I'll borrow one from my university's library, let you know if that works. Thanks again!